# Is there a way programmatically I can check if the user wants to upload a file as new version?

Tags: document-library, event-receivers, file-upload

We have a document library and we added an event receiver to move the files out of the root folder accordingly to our business requirements.  I am having issues now because I am trying to check if the “Add as a new version to existing files” is checked(In the Upload File Dialog box this question is asked).  Is there a way programmatically I can check if this box has been checked?   Thanks for any help you can provide on this.

Comment: Interesting question! Is there anything in the Before or AfterProperties you can use?